# How to get back button to trigger route guard if only parameter in route changes in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following route:

```
{ name: 'items', path: 'items/:id', component: () => import('pages/Childitems'), props: true}
```

If I browse to this route, then all router guards and component hooks are triggered normally, e.g.

`http://localhost:8081/items/1`
`http://localhost:8081/items/57`
`http://localhost:8081/items/58`

The above sequence of addresses works fine - all expected router hooks, such as `beforeUpdate` and `updated` are triggered.

However if I use the browser's back and forward buttons to reach those URLs, then those hooks are not triggered.

Here is the component code:

```
export default {
    name: 'items',
    created: function() {
        console.log('items/:id hook – created');
    },
    beforeMount () {
        console.log('items/:id hook beforeMount');
    },
    mounted () {
        console.log('items/:id hook mounted');
    },
    beforeUpdate () {
        console.log('items/:id hook beforeUpdate');
    },
    updated () {
        console.log('items/:id hook updated');
    },
    activated () {
        console.log('items/:id hook activated');
    },
    beforeDestroy () {
        console.log('items/:id hook beforeDestroy');
    },
    destroyed () {
        console.log('items/:id hook destroyed');
    },
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        console.log('update items beforeRouteUpdate');
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
        console.log('update items beforeRouteUpdate');
    },
    beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
        console.log('update items beforeRouteUpdate');
    }
}
```

How can I get them to trigger? Or what hook can I use for the forward and back buttons?

Comment: Try the `beforeRouteEnter()` method

Comment: @RuChernChong it also does not trigger. Nor does `beforeRouteUpdate` nor `beforeRouteLeave`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the docs: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

So I just add the following to my controller:

```
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
      console.log('route parameter changed');
      console.log(to.params.id);
      console.log(from.params.id);
    }
  },
```

Comment: This is correct, but it only handles the case for when the VueRoute component is the same with browser back/forward. When going back/forward over different VueRoute components, beforeRoute* methods must still be used. I'm sure you know this, but just adding for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I've found out that the beforeRouteUpdate hook is created in v2.2 (see documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

If you are using a vue version prior to that you could try setting the "canReuse" to false in the route object? So:

```
{
    canReuse: false,
    name: 'items', 
    path: 'items/:id', 
    component: () => import('pages/Childitems'), 
    props: true
}
```

This should force the vue-router to reload the component every time the route is called with different parameters.

This had fixed the problem for me when making a search page in which the component was not firing it's lifecycle hooks upon query changes.